# Jetpack Compose + Jetpack Paging + Clean architecture = impossible?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I want to migrate my current codebase to Jetpack Compose. Currently I am using Paging v2, so that's the first step that I have to make. In Paging v2 I had a ViewModel that had `val pagedData = LiveData<PagingList<Something>>` exposed as a field. That was great, as it could have been used by `PagingAdapter`, but also in some cases, like for tracking purposes, I could access that data by simply calling `pagedData.value.orEmpty()` and I could easily check if the data displayed for the user is empty or not. With `val migratedPagedData = PagingSource(...) { ... }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)` it isn't that easy. In fact - is it even possible? `migratedPagedData` is of type `Flow<PagingData<Something>>`. `PagingData` has another flow inside, but it is internal, hence not available outside of Jetpack Paging code...

So basically I want to store in ViewModel all items that are currently available in `PagingAdapter`. Is there any better way to do such thing?

Of course I've thought of passing the data from adapter to ViewModel, but that doesn't seem Clean. Data is coming from ViewModel to the View, so why would the View tell ViewModel what it got? That's the opposite of clean.
I've also been thinking about making `PagingSource` capable of registering listeners that would be called on each `load(...)` call, but that seem to be risky (and ugly) in terms of registering listener too early/too late, managing invalidations and so on.

Can somebody provide their insight?

Comment: No, It's possible. I have used in my project with these principles.

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: https://medium.com/@mohammadjoumani/paging-with-clean-architecture-in-jetpack-compose-775fbf589256

Comment: @ChiragThummar That's not what I meant. I want to be able to see what data is loaded in the adapter. Since the data is coming to the adapter from ViewModel, it would make sense that viewModel can access that data. But it can't, due to the fact that `PagingData` has flow with data, but it is internal for paging code, so we cannot access it. Writing code that would make the view notify viewModel what data is visible would break clean architecture.

Comment: Then you have to write your own paging logic